# PHP Pig Latin, Y as both vowel and consonant

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to solve the problem of translating to pig latin using PHP. I'm stuck, because Y can be both a vowel or a consonant depending on context. If Y is on the beginning of the word, is considered a consonant, if it is on the middle is considered a vowel.

For example "yellow style" becomes "ellowyay ylestay". With the rules being: "Words that start with a vowel (A, E, I, O, U) simply have "WAY" appended to the end of the word.
Words that start with a consonant have all consonant letters up to the first vowel moved to the end of the word (as opposed to just the first consonant letter), and "AY" is appended. ('Y' is counted as a vowel in this context)"

My code is as following:

```
class Config{

public static $vowels = 'aeiou';
public static $vowelTermination = "way";
public static $consonants = 'b-df-hj-np-tv-z';
}

class Piglatin
{

public function convert($input)
{
    $return = "";
    $wordArray = explode(" ", $input);

    foreach($wordArray as $word){
        $return .= $this->translate($word);
        $return .= " ";
    }

    return rtrim($return);
}

public function translate($input)
{
    $translation = "";

    if(!empty($input)){

        if(is_numeric($input)){
            return $input;
        }

        if($this->startVowel($input)){
            $input = $input . Config::$vowelTermination;
            return $input;
        }

        if($this->startConsonant($input) && strlen($input)===1 ){
            return $input.'ay';
        }

        if($this->startConsonant($input)){
            $input = preg_replace('/^([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]*)([aeiouy].*)$/', "$2$1ay", $input);
            return $input;
        }
    }

    return $translation;
}

public function startVowel($input)
{
    $regex = '/^['.Config::$vowels.']/i';

    if(preg_match($regex, $input)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function startConsonant($input)
{
    $regex = '/^['.Config::$consonants.']/i';

    if(preg_match($regex, $input)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Which given the input "yellow style" produces "yelloway ylestay" which is close to the expected result, but not quite.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: See https://github.com/davidyell/Pig-Latin-Translator/blob/master/lib/translate.php

Comment: Up top you say: `For example "yellow style" becomes "ellowyay ylestay". With the rules being:`. Down on the bottom you say: `Which given the input "yellow style" produces "ellowyay ylestay" which is close to the expected result, but not quite`

Comment: Not Duplicate but exists in github :D @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: "ellowyay ylestay" is the expected result, and the result I'm having is "yelloway ylestay".

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you've got 3 separate conditions.
This regex uses a branch reset (parallel groups) with those conditions.
Each condition must be enforced and that's what this does.

Note that it does not count for boundary's, but I would use a whitespace boundary if you need one.  `(?<!\S)(?: regex )(?!\S)`
Also, you could add other characters to the `[a-z]` class or `[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]`
but not to the vowels class `[aeiouy]` or the `[y]` class.

Basically it is
Find `(?i)(?|([aeiou][a-z]*)()|([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]+)([aeiouy][a-z]*)|([y]+[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]*)([aeiouy][a-z]*))`
Replace `$2$1ay`

Expanded

```
 (?i)                              # Modifier - case independent
 (?|                               # Branch Reset
      ( [aeiou] [a-z]* )                # (1), Condition: starts with a vowel
      ( )                               # (2)
   |  
      ( [b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]+ )           # (1), Condition: starts with a non-Y consonant
      ( [aeiouy] [a-z]* )               # (2), and Y as vowel
   |  
      ( [y]+ [b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]* )      # (1), Condition: starts with a Y consonant
      ( [aeiouy] [a-z]* )               # (2), and Y as vowel
 )
```

Sample input  `yellow style atak yyerto yystay start`
Sample output `ellowyay ylestay atakay ertoyyay ayyystay artstay`

Comment: It makes total sense. Will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: @CláudioRibeiro - What did you settle on?

Answer (score 0):

The regex in your `preg_replace` doesn't match a `Y` in the first capture group: `([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]*)`. So the groups end-up as `$1=''` and `$2='yellow'`, hence the result is `yelloway`.

I've not tested it, but this should work, no?

```
preg_replace('/^([b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*)([aeiouy].*)$/', "$2$1ay", $input)
```

Comment: This way he stops considering the Y in the middle of the word as a vowel. For example, I'm now getting "ellowyay estylay" instead of "'ellowyay ylestay" whoch is the expected result.